# Magento 2.3.0 How to override wishlist & compare product list page using plugin

Tags: frontend, wishlist, magento2.3.0, compare, after-plugin

I want to override wishlist & compare product grid using plugin. after that i would like to append custom div under `class="product-image-container"`.

I try & search a lot but no luck. is there any way to achieve thing?

I try below way for wishlist grid.

> Namespace/Modulename/etc/forntend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items">
    <plugin name="Namespace_Modulename::wishlistProduct" type="namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Customer\Wishlist\Items" sortOrder="18" />
</type>
```

> Namespace/Modulename/Plugin/Customer/Wishlist/items.php

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Customer\Wishlist;

class Items
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
 */
protected $layout;   
public function __construct(        
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
) { //die('test called');
    $this->layout = $layout; 
}

public function afterGetColumns(\Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items  $subject, $result       
) {
    var_dump($subject->getProduct());die('called');
    $labelHtml = $this->layout->createBlock('Namespace\Modulename\Block\Label')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::product/label.phtml')->toHtml();
    return $result.$labelHtml;        
} 
}
```

What i missing or wrong in above code?

---

**Edit :**

How can i create after plugin for class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare` ?

I try with below way but not working.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Namespace_Modulename::compareProduct" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Compare\ListCompare" sortOrder="19" />
</type>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you use around Plugin, which used to override function

Comment: can you share any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution using below way.

**For Wishlist product page.**

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image">
    <plugin name="Namespace_Modulename::wishlistProduct" type="Namaespace\Modulename\Plugin\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" sortOrder="18" />
</type>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Plugin/Customer/Wishlist/Item/Column/Image.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column;
use Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data;

class Image
{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $layout;   
    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        Data $dataHelper
    ) {        
        $this->layout = $layout; 
        $this->registry = $registry;        
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }

    public function afterToHtml(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $item = $subject->getItem();
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        if($product){
            if($this->dataHelper->isEnabled()){
                $result .= $this->layout->createBlock('Namespace\Modulename\Block\Label')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::product/label.phtml')->toHtml();            
            }
        }
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

**For Compare product page.**

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare">
    <plugin name="Namespace_Modulename::compareProduct" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Compare\ListCompare" sortOrder="19" />
</type>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Plugin/Catalog/Product/Compare/ListCompare.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Compare;
use Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data;

class ListCompare
{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $layout;   

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        Data $dataHelper
    ) {
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }

    public function afterGetReviewsSummaryHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare $subject, $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $templateType = false,
        $displayIfNoReviews = false
    ) {        
        if($product){
            if($this->dataHelper->isEnabled()){
                $result .= $this->layout->createBlock('Namespace\Modulename\Block\Label')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::product/label.phtml')->toHtml();            
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```